# Is it possible to put --preserve-merges in the gitconfig

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'd like to set up at least one of my repositories (I'm fine if the setting is global) to always preserve branches when I rebase. Is there a way to set that in my gitconfig?

Comment: I don't think you can put that flag in your config file

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "no"; the medium-length answer is "sort of"; and the long answer is "you probably don't want to do that". :-)

The short answer is so easy because there is literally no configuration entry for `git rebase` to set preserve-merges mode automatically.

The "sort of" answer is because `git pull` *can* be configured to run `git rebase --preserve-merges` automatically.  Remember that `git pull` is, in essence, just the pair of commands `git fetch && git something`, with the *`something`* part configurable: either `merge` or `rebase`, and if `rebase`, what flag(s) to use.  But this only affects the rebase commands run by `git pull`, not the ones you run yourself.

The long answer is more complicated.  While preserving merges *is* probably generally superior, in at least a few ways, to discarding them when rebasing, the fact is that rebase *cannot* preserve them.  The only thing it can do, once some commits have been copied to new commits, is *re-perform them*.  This can have new and/or different merge conflicts, vs the last time the merge was done.  You should also pay close attention to the restrictions on merge preservation in [the `git rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html).

Without getting into a lot of detail, it always seems to me that most commit graph subsets that "should be" rebased, rarely have any *internal* merges.  If such a graph subset has a single *final* merge, you can simply strip away that merge (with `git reset`) before rebasing, and re-do that single merge manually at the end.  (In fact, `git rebase` normally drops merge commits entirely, so you don't have to run the `git reset` itself in some cases.  The one where you do have to run it is when the merge is into the branch onto which you intend to rebase.  This is where `git pull` actually does the right thing when it uses `git rebase -p`, except that it fails to check for, and warn about, internal merges, which are sort of warning signs that rebasing might not be a good idea.)

Comment: “it always seems to me that most commit graph subsets that "should be" rebased, rarely have any internal merges.”—One exception being the original author of `--preserve-merges` and `--rebase-merges`.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration variable `rebase.rebaseMerges` is slated for inclusion
in the next version of Git (2.41.0). It allows you to always use
`--rebase-merges`.

#### History/Context

1. 1.5.3: git-rebase(1) learns `--preserve-merges`, at the same time as
   it learns `--interactive`
2. 2.22: git-rebase(1) learns `--rebase-merges` and `--preserve-merges`
   is deprecated
3. 2.34: git-rebase(1) unlearns `--preserve-merges` (read: now you get a
   fatal error if you try to use it)
4. 2.41.0-rc0: git-config(1) (I guess?) learns `rebase.rebaseMerges`